# Constructing Java hashmap from Spark dataframe

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with Java 8 in my project.

I need to construct a loop up hashmap from given dataframe as below:

```java
List ll = Arrays.asList(
      ("aaaa", 11),
      ("aaa", 12),
      ("aa", 13),
      ("a", 14)
    )

Dataset<Row> codeValudeDf = ll.toDF( "code", "value")
```

Given the above dataframe I need to create a hashmap

i.e.

```java
Map<String, String> lookUpHm = new Hashmap<>();

lookUpHm  => aaaa->11  , aaa->12 , aa->13, a->14
```

How can it it be done in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```java
 List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create("aaaa", 11),
                RowFactory.create("aaa", 12),
                RowFactory.create("aa", 13),
                RowFactory.create("a", 14)
        );

        Dataset<Row> codeValudeDf = spark.createDataFrame(rows, new StructType()
                .add("code", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
                .add("value", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()));
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        codeValudeDf.collectAsList().forEach(row -> map.put(row.getString(0), row.getInt(1)));

        System.out.println(map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() +"->"+ e.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[ ", " ]")));
        // [ aaa->12, aa->13, a->14, aaaa->11 ]
```

Comment: if dataset is huge, codeValudeDf.collectAsList() will collect data in driver, that would be an issue. We want it to be distributed and map should be prepared and collected from distributed datasets. How to do it/

Answer (score 1):

Simple add a new column of type map using withColumn and do a collect on your dataframe.

```
codeValudeDf.withColumn("some_map",
map(col("code"), col("value"))).select("some_map").distinct().collect()
```

Comment: getting error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations(intersect, except, etc.), but the type of column some_map is map<string,int>;;